# nginx - directory index of ... is forbidden, even for chmod 777

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I'm trying to run rails app using nginx and unicorn based on Ryan Bates railcast (it's brand new `rails new testapp`).

So first step I want to test nginx only, no unicorn - just to work on `index.html` in `public/`. I point it to my testapp direcory, and get "index of "/var/www/testapp" is forbidden" error (I even set it all for 777 and got the same error)

My username: `deployer`, nginx: worker process user is `www-data`.

In my sites-enabled for my testapp I have symlink to `/var/www/testapp/config/nginx.conf`
:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name beta.sitename.pl;
  root /var/www/testapp;
}
```

Owner of `www/` and all it's files and subdirectories is `deployer` and group `www-data`, all is set to 775.

Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting directory index properly, for example:

> index index.html default.html index.php;

in your location block or use `autoindex on` option.

[More info here](http://www.pannix.net/585/nginx-and-the-importance-of-punctuation/)

Comment: ah, sorry, didn't noticed it is for rails, it seems the question have been edited.